# Assembly multiple conditional jumps

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I can't organize jumps for the following pseudo code (to Assembly 8086):

```
array = ...numbers set...
cl = 2
num = 0
si = 0
while(si != 11)
{
   ax = 0
   al = array[si]

   // divide with assembly
   div cl
   if(ah = 0)
   {
      n+1
   }
   si+1
}
```

I've tried something like that:

```
.data
array db 0Fh, 45h, 0A1h, 78h, 0CFh, 0AAh, 8Fh, 19h ; Array
p db 0 ; Number of even numbers in the array
.code
xor si, si
xor cx, cx
mov cl, 2
again:
xor ax, ax 
mov al, array[si]
div cl
cmp ah, 0
je eq
inc si
cmp si, 11
jne again
eq:
inc p
inc si
cmp si, 11
jne again
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do the `inc p` right under the `cmp ah, 0` jump and only jump over it if they're not equal:

```
...
cmp ah, 0
jne noteq
inc p
noteq:
inc si
cmp si, 11
jne again
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you are missing is a jump to the end just before the `eq` label. Currently, if the last iteration ends in the `ah`!=0 branch, it will fall through to the `eq` label, increase `si` to 12 and jump back to the `again` label. You could also reorganize the code such that only the `inc p` is jumped over, so both cases would use the same `si` comparison (similar to your pseudocode).

Note, if you only want to check for even/odd numbers, just testing the lowest bit is a simpler way.